# Using SQL to find the total number times a product has been bought in one query

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to find the most optimal way to return a recordset containing a list of all products that have been bought by customers and how many of each have been sold.

Table ORDERS is laid out like this:

```
CustomerID ProductID (etc)
1              10
1              10
1              11
2              10
4              9
```

This is a many to many relationship, so the same customer can have multiple records and can buy the same product multiple times. I need to get a recordset containing the following info, using a query I can put in a stored procedure:

```
ProductID NumSales
1            3
2            1
4            1
```

Any help would be appreciated - I'm fairly new to advanced SQL, and I'd love it if you could give me a basic rundown of how the query works so I can learn to do it myself in the future - I have the feeling it's fairly simple, but I just don't know the syntax yet!

Comment: What about if you have products with 0 sales? Do you really want them to be absent from your result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select ProductID, count(*) as NumSales from Orders group by ProductID
```

If there's a quantity field there too, try this:

```
select ProductID, sum(Quantity) as TotalQty from Orders group by ProductID
```

Comment: That did it, I think I was just making it over-complicated in my head. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
select p. PRODUCT_ID, p.PRODUCT_DESC, max(o. PRODUCT_QUANTITY )from PRODUCT p
join ORDER_ITEMS o
on o.PRODUCT_ID =p.PRODUCT_ID;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).